# CloudWatch Alarm on uptime of ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I am setting up an cloudwatch alarm for the uptime of EC2 instance as when the uptime of instance exceed 5 hours then alarm trigger.

Please help to find out the solution to this problem as I am new to aws cloudwatch.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: There is no metric provided in Amazon CloudWatch for "uptime" of an instance. Can you explain to us your actual use-case for wanting this information? There might be a better way to achieve your goal. Feel free to edit your question to add more details.

Comment: Cloudwatch is overkill for what you are asking. A simple cron script can take care of your needs. Use sandbox SES (free) to send you a mail.